# Router and Provider inheritance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm learning React and want to use Redux with React Router. 
Does it matter is Provider inside Router or opposite? What will be better:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Browser>
   // routes
  </Browser>
</Provder>
```

or

```
<Browser>    
  <Provider store={store}>
   // routes
  </Provder>
</Browser>
```

At first look I can use the both ways. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on whether you want to sync the state of the routing with your store. For example, if you are using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#tutorial), you want to set up, the `Provider` first and the `Router` inside.

> From the docs:
>
> ```
> import React from 'react'
> import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
> import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
> import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
> import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
> import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
>
> import reducers from '<project-path>/reducers'
>
> // Add the reducer to your store on the `routing` key
> const store = createStore(
>   combineReducers({
>     ...reducers,
>     routing: routerReducer
>   })
> )
>
> // Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
> const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <Provider store={store}>
>     { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
>     <Router history={history}>
>       <Route path="/" component={App}>
>         <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
>         <Route path="bar" component={Bar}/>
>       </Route>
>     </Router>
>   </Provider>,
>   document.getElementById('mount')
> )
> ```